# How do you scroll the canvas in EV3 Classroom?

Tags: ev3, programming

I have EV3 classroom installed on Mac. I am writing a pretty lengthy program that does not fit in a single screen. However, I am not able to figure how to scroll down or move sideways. This should be simple, but embarrassingly, I can not figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Click on a blank area of the canvas and drag while still holding the mouse button to pan.